# OnClick of Download button should download all Attachment of Selected account as zip file

Tags: apex

I have created a List View button as Download Attachment  on Account Object when I select account a new VF page with all attachment  of selected account are displayed. On Same VF page I have command button Download button so onclick of these button i want selected attachment to be compress and make selected attachment as a zip file.

Following is VF page:

```
<apex:page id="main" standardController="Account" extensions="AccountController" recordSetVar="account">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.js_zip, '/dist/jszip.js')}"/>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      //This will load as soon as the page is ready and will setup our slider
    var str;
    var count; var checkedSize; var selectedFiles; var zipFile = new JSZip();

      var selectedCount=0;
      function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID){
          //str='';          
          var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsById("$Component.form.selectedF");
          var isAlreadyChecked=false;
          for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++){  
                  isAlreadyChecked = inputCheckBox[i].checked;                  
                  inputCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                  console.log('***'+str.indexOf(inputCheckBox[i].nextSibling.value));
                      if(inputCheckBox[i].checked){
                          if(str.indexOf(inputCheckBox[i].nextSibling.value) < 0){
                              //selectedCount++; 
                              str += inputCheckBox[i].nextSibling.value+',';  
                          }                                                 
                      }
                      else{
                          str = str.replace(inputCheckBox[i].nextSibling.value+',','');  
                          //selectedCount--;
                      }
          }
          //$('#selCount').html(selectedCount+' Selected');
          document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.selectedF}').value = str;    
          countSelected();   
      }
      function selectThis(ele,id){
          if(ele.checked){
              str+=id+',';
              //selectedCount++;   
               console.log("If ="+str);           
          }
          else{
              str = str.replace(id+',','');          
              //selectedCount--;
              console.log("Else "+str);
          }
          //$('#selCount').html(selectedCount+' Selected');
          document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.selectedF}').value = str;
          countSelected();
      }
      function countSelected(){
          var strValues = document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.selectedF}').value;
          if(strValues)
              selectedCount = strValues.substring(0, str.length - 1).split(',').length;
          else
              selectedCount = 0;
          $('#selCount').html(selectedCount+' Selected');
      }
      function reCheckAll(){
          if(str!=''){
              //str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
              var arrIds = str.split(',');
              var checkedCount = 0; var allCount = $("input:checkbox.selectBox").length; 
              console.log('arrIds'+arrIds);    
              $("input:checkbox.selectBox").each(function(){
                  console.log($(this).next().val()+'--:'+arrIds.indexOf($(this).next().val()));
                  if(arrIds.indexOf($(this).next().val())>=0){
                      $(this).prop('checked',true);
                      checkedCount++;
                  }
              });
              console.log('**'+checkedCount+','+allCount);
              if(checkedCount == allCount)
                  $('input[id$="checkAllId"]').prop('checked',true);
              else
                  $('input[id$="checkAllId"]').prop('checked',false);                          
          }else{
               $("input:checkbox.selectBox").prop('checked',false);
          }
      }
      function closePop(){
          zipFile = new JSZip();          
          hidePopup();
      }
      function hidePopup(){                    
          $('#overlay').hide(); $('#fade').hide(); 
          document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.selectedF}').value = '';
          str = '';
          $('.selectBox').prop('checked',false);
          $('.chkAll').prop('checked',false);
          $('#selCount').html('0 Selected');
      }


      function downloadAtts(){
        count=0;
        zipFile = new JSZip();
        if (str==null || str==''){            
            showPageMessage('ERROR', 'Please, Select at least one attachment to Download.');
            return false;
        }
        var strAtts = str;
        strAtts = strAtts.substring(0, strAtts.length - 1);
        var arrIds = strAtts.split(',');
        console.log("--spliting Id--"+arrIds);
        checkedSize = arrIds.length;
        $('#count').text(count+1);
        $('#total').text(checkedSize);
        $('#txtStatus').show();
        $('#progress').show();
        $('#complete').hide();
        $('#percent').css('width',0+'%');                        
        if (checkedSize < 200) {
            $('#overlay').show();$('#fade').show();            
            selectedFiles = arrIds;
            compress(count);                
        } else
            alert("You cannot download more than 200 attachments at once.");
      }
      function compress(cnt){          
            attachmentzip.AccountController.getAttachment(selectedFiles[count], recordRetrieved, {
                  escape: false
            });
        }        
        function recordRetrieved(result, event) {
                if (event.status) {                    
                    //Refresh zip process status                        
                    count++;                    
                    //Add the file
                    compressFile(zipFile,result.attName, result.attEncodedBody); 
                    $('#count').text(count);
                    $('#percent').css('width',(count/checkedSize)*100+'%');                                        
                    if(count<checkedSize)
                          compress(count);                 
                    //Once all the selected files have been compressed
                    if (count == checkedSize) {
                        //Send form
                        sendZip(zipFile);                                  
                    }
                } else if (event.type === 'exception') {                    
                    hidePopup();
                    if(event.statusCode==414)
                        alert('You can only compress upto 15MB of file.');
                    else
                        alert('Exception: ' + event.message);
                    return false;                    
                } else {
                    hidePopup();
                    alert('Message: ' + event.message);
                }
            }
        //Compress one single file    
        function compressFile(zipFile, name, data) {
            zipFile.file(name, data, {
                base64: true
            });            
        }

        //Generate and upload zip file
        function sendZip(zipFile){    
            var data = zipFile.generate();
            var filename ='{!JSENCODE(parentName)}_Attachments';   //'{!JSENCODE(ParentID)}_Attachments';
            var blobLink = document.getElementById('blob');
            try {
                blobLink.download = filename + ".zip";
                blobLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(zipFile.generate({
                    type: "blob"
                }));
                $('#percent').css('background-color','Green');
                $('#complete').show();
                $('#txtStatus').hide();
                //blobLink.click();
            } catch (e) {
                blobLink.innerHTML += " (not supported on this browser)";
            }
        }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 0;
        str = document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.selectedF}').value;
        //Instantiate JSZip        
        $('#dAllAtts').click(function() {
            downloadAtts();                   
        }); //end click                        
    });

   </script>

   <apex:outputPanel id="msgid">
   <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
</apex:outputPanel> 

<apex:form id="frm" >
    <apex:inputHidden id="selectedF" value="{!selectedFiles}"/>
        <apex:outputLabel rendered="{!if(listWrapper.size>0,false,true)}"><h1><center> No Attachment Found ! Click on Back button.</center></h1></apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:pageBlock id="pblock" rendered="{!if(listWrapper.size>0,true,false)}">
               <apex:pageBlockSection title="All Attachments" collapsible="false" columns="1">
                     <apex:pageBlockTable title="All Attachments" id="tbDownload" value="{!listWrapper}" var="w">
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">
                                <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')" id="checkAllId"/>
                            </apex:facet> 
                            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!w.selected}" styleClass="selectBox" onchange="selectThis(this,'{!JSENCODE(w.aid)}')"/>
                            <apex:inputHidden value="{!w.aid}"/>
                         </apex:column>
                         <apex:column value="{!w.attach }" headerValue="Attachments" id="cmdSort"/>
                         <apex:column value="{!w.BodyLength }" headerValue="Size" id="cmdSort1"/>
                         <apex:column value="{!w.Cdate}" headerValue="Created Date" id="cmdSort2"/>
                         <apex:column headerValue="Click to view" >
                             <apex:outputLink title="Download File" Rendered="{!w.isAttachment}" value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!w.aid}" target="_blank">
                                Download
                             </apex:outputLink>      
                             <apex:outputLink title="Download File" Rendered="{!NOT(w.isAttachment)}" value="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!w.aId}" target="_blank">      
                                Download        
                             </apex:outputLink>
                          </apex:column>
                          <!--<apex:facet name="footer">Showing Page # {!pageNumber} of {!totalPages}</apex:facet>-->
                    </apex:pageBlockTable> 
                    <div id="selCount" style="margin-left:10px;background-color:#ffe324;float:left; width:80px;">0 Selected</div>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:actionFunction name="showPageMessage" action="{!showPageMessage}" rerender="msgid">       
                  <apex:param name="level" assignTo="{!level}" value="" />      
                  <apex:param name="message" assignTo="{!message}" value="" />      
                </apex:actionFunction>
                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                   <input type="button" value="Download Attachments" onclick="downloadAtts()"  id="dAllAtts" class="btn"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class AccountController 
{
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;
    set<id> ids = new set<id>();
    public string selectedFiles { get; set; }
    public string parentName{get;set;} 
    public String message {get; set;}  
    public Id parentId{get;set;}
    public list<Attachment> lstAttach{get;set;}
    public String level {get; set;}
    public List<WrapperClass> listWrapper{get;set;}
    public Boolean allBool{get;set;}
    public Boolean Checked{get;set;}
    Integer i=0;
    public AccountController (ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController)
    {
         List<Account> selectedAccounts = new List<Account>(); 
         selectedAccounts=standardController.getSelected();
         system.debug('**Selected Account**'+selectedAccounts.size());
         for(Account selectedAccount : selectedAccounts)
         {
            ids.add(selectedAccount.id);
         }
         lstAttach = new list<Attachment>([select id, name, BodyLength , CreatedDate, Owner.Name from Attachment where parentid=:ids]);
         system.debug('**Selected Account**'+lstAttach.size());
         listWrapper=new List<WrapperClass>();
         i=0;
         for(Attachment a:lstAttach)
         {
              //public WrapperClass(String objAttachment,Id cid,DateTime Cdate,Integer BLength, boolean isAttach)
            WrapperClass w= new WrapperClass(a.Name,a.id,a.CreatedDate,a.BodyLength,true,i);
            listWrapper.add(w);
            i++;
         }  
     }
     public class WrapperClass
     {
        public String attach {get;set;} 
        public Boolean selected { get; set; }
        public Id aid{get;set;}
        public Integer BodyLength {get;set;}   
        public DateTime Cdate {get;set;}
        public boolean isAttachment{get;set;}
        public Attachment ObjAttach{get;set;}
        public Integer Index{get;set;}

        public WrapperClass(String objAttachment,Id cid,DateTime Cdate,Integer BLength, boolean isAttach,Integer i)
        {
            BodyLength = BLength/1024;
            attach = objAttachment;
            aid=cid;
            this.isAttachment = isAttach;
            this.Cdate=Cdate;
            this.Index=i;
            selected = false;
        }
    }
    public PageReference bumpCases()
    {       
        // Get the selected records (optional, you can use getSelected to obtain IDs and do your own SOQL)
        List<Account> selectedAccounts = (List<Account>) standardController.getSelected();
        if(selectedAccounts != null){
        for(Account selectedAccount : selectedAccounts)
        {
            ids.add(selectedAccount.id);
        }
        lstAttach = new list<Attachment>([select id, name, BodyLength , CreatedDate, Owner.Name from Attachment where parentid=:ids]);

    }
    return null;
    }
    /*public void selectAll()
    {
         if(allBool)
         {
             for(Attachment acc:lstAttach)
             {
                 checked=true;
             }
         } 
         else
         {
             for(Attachment acc:lstAttach)
             {
                 checked=false;
             }
         }  
    }*/  
    public void showPageMessage() {     
      if(level == 'ERROR') {        
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, message));     
      }     
    } 
    public PageReference viewAttach()
    {
        ID lid=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('ViewAttach');
        return new Pagereference ('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+lid);
    }
}
```